# Post table name as the direction

Tags: php, mysql

I have two radio button, which each of them has value of table name.

```
     <input type="radio" name="method" value="tableOne"/>
     <input type="radio" name="method" value="tableTwo"/>


<?php
     $table=$_POST['method'];
     insert into $table (blabblalalbalblabal.........)...
?>
```

But it does't seem to work.

Any idea  please?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to insert data in your DB?

Comment: Please clarify what you want and whats not working!

Comment: Are these two tables using same table structure ?

Comment: @AllenChak, no. they have different column, only id which are same.

Comment: revise your SQL, remove the content after the table name, such as `INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('bla', 'bla bla', 'bla bla bla')`

Comment: I have tried many way in that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @klaudia Do you want to display the user input or do you want to insert data in your DB? Your code have many error's so i don't see what your goal is

Comment: Could you provide the HTML (FORM), PHP Code (related insert data) AND Table structure (tableOne & tableTwo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your insert statement using a `IF` to determinate.

```
<?php
    $deliveryMethod = $_POST['deliveryMethod'];
    if('InfiStallStock' == $deliveryMethod){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_InfiStallStock (tableOneFieldA, tableOneFieldB, tableOneFieldC) VALUES('$member_oneremail', '$infistallLocation', '$delivery_city')");
    }elseif('DeliveryStock' == $deliveryMethod){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_DeliveryStock  (tableTwoFieldX, tableTwoFieldY, tableTwoFieldZ) VALUES('$member_oneremail', '$delivery_address', '$deliveryService')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is what I had been looking for so far before deciding to insert into table name. I will give it a try. Thanks